# SQL - Update a table with Join

Tags: sql

Table name - Emlpoyee

Emp_id, Emp_name, Address, Area of Expertise

---

Table name - Pallocation

Emp_id, PROJECT_ID, STAFF_COST

---

Table name - Projects

PROJECT_ID, Project_name, Client

---

Q) Change the staff cost in PALLOCATION of Kayleigh Donald in the TV ad project from 900 to 1200

(I don't think there is a need to write all the relevant data within the table I guess...?)

Comment: Answered again, check It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SQL-SERVER` should be something like:

```
UPDATE pa
SET pa.STAFF_COST = 1200
FROM Pallocation pa 
JOIN Emlpoyee e 
   ON e.Emp_id = pa.Emp_id
JOIN Projects pr
   ON pr.PROJECT_ID = pa.PROJECT_ID
WHERE pr.Client = 'Kayleigh Donald' AND pr.Project_Name = 'TV ad'
```

Comment: And this works for which dbms? (Product specific answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this... for SQL Server 2012

```
update  Pallocation
    set     Staff_Cost = 1200
    from    Employee        emp
    join    Pallocation     palloc
    on      emp.Emp_id = palloc.palloc
    join    Projects        pro
        on  pro.PROJECT_ID = palloc.PROJECT_ID
    where   emp.Emp_name = 'Kayleigh Donald'
        and pro.Project_name = 'TV ad project'
```

Comment: This is wrong, need to SET `STAFF_COST` not `Pallocation`

Comment: thank u Mr. Stanislovas Kalašnikovas

Comment: And this works for which dbms? (Product specific answer...)

Answer (score 1):

This link may help you.

MySql-(http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/)

Sql-(http://sqlandme.com/2013/06/18/sql-server-update-table-with-inner-join/)

Answer (score 0):

Is it specified in the excercice that you need to use a join?
Otherwise, you can solve this using subqueries.

```
UPDATE Pallocation SET STAFF_COST = 1200
WHERE Emp_id = (SELECT Emp_id FROM Employee WHERE Emp_name = "Kayleigh Donald")
  AND PROJECT_ID = (SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects  WHERE Project_name = "TV")
```

But Stackoverflow isn't about solving your excercices Ofcourse...
You have to at least try it yourself and show us how far you got.